# Invalid Polygons from ST_MakeSolid(ST_ConvexHull(...))

Tags: sfcgal

The aim: a TINZ has been derived from at least two lidar scans with the results stitched together into a single mesh. The original scans are unavailable, and the stitched mesh is rejected by sfcgal functions as having an invalid structure.

I'm exploring the approach of reducing the mesh to points again and trying to reconstruct the mesh using postGis functions. The following test example uses a simple 3D cube as the POLYHEDRALSURFACEZ source:

```
WITH getpoints AS
(SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(ST_MakeSolid('POLYHEDRALSURFACEZ(
                            ((0 0 0, 0 0 1, 0 1 1, 0 1 0, 0 0 0)),
                            ((0 0 0, 0 1 0, 1 1 0, 1 0 0, 0 0 0)),
                            ((0 0 0, 1 0 0, 1 0 1, 0 0 1, 0 0 0)),
                            ((1 1 0, 1 1 1, 1 0 1, 1 0 0, 1 1 0)),
                            ((0 1 0, 0 1 1, 1 1 1, 1 1 0, 0 1 0)),
                            ((0 0 1, 1 0 1, 1 1 1, 0 1 1, 0 0 1)) )'))).geom)

SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Tesselate(ST_MakeSolid(ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(getpoints.geom)))))

FROM getpoints;
```

However, this fails with the error:

```
ERROR: Polygon is invalid : points don't lie in the same plane : POLYGON((0/1 0/1 0/1,0/1 1/1 1/1,1/1 1/1 0/1,1/1 0/1 0/1,0/1 0/1 0/1)) SQL state: XX000
```

I've checked the ST_ConvexHull and ST_MakeSolid functions using ST_IsValid and they both return true. Have also tried ST_MakeValid on ST_ConvexHull and ST_MakeSolid, but this makes no difference.

If I tesselate the test cube directly like this, it works fine:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Tesselate('POLYHEDRALSURFACEZ(
                            ((0 0 0, 0 0 1, 0 1 1, 0 1 0, 0 0 0)),
                            ((0 0 0, 0 1 0, 1 1 0, 1 0 0, 0 0 0)),
                            ((0 0 0, 1 0 0, 1 0 1, 0 0 1, 0 0 0)),
                            ((1 1 0, 1 1 1, 1 0 1, 1 0 0, 1 1 0)),
                            ((0 1 0, 0 1 1, 1 1 1, 1 1 0, 0 1 0)),
                            ((0 0 1, 1 0 1, 1 1 1, 0 1 1, 0 0 1)) )'));
```

So why are the outputs of the other functions not valid for ST_Tesselate???

Comment: I believe the problem is to do with dump and collect, not returning things in the right order. sfgcal is  very fussy about 3d surfaces being in the correct order/orientation. If you run, `elect st_astext(st_tesselate(ST_MakeSolid('POLYHEDRALSURFACEZ(((0 0 0, 0 0 1, 0 1 1, 0 1 0, 0 0 0)), ((0 0 0, 0 1 0, 1 1 0, 1 0 0, 0 0 0)), ((0 0 0, 1 0 0, 1 0 1, 0 0 1, 0 0 0)),((1 1 0, 1 1 1, 1 0 1, 1 0 0, 1 1 0)),                ((0 1 0, 0 1 1, 1 1 1, 1 1 0, 0 1 0)), ((0 0 1, 1 0 1, 1 1 1, 0 1 1, 0 0 1)) )')));` you get a geometry collection containing TIN Z.

Comment: ST_DumpPoints should reduce the POLYHEDRALSURFACEZ structure to a list of points, which really just means removing the ((...)) polygon delimiters from the POLYHEDRALSURFACEZ  representation. ST_Collect turns the point list into a geometrycollection. ST_ConvexHull should create a shape around the resulting point set. At this step, the order of the points shouldn't matter. Which makes it plausible that the output of ST_ConvexHull is not valid. Would this depend upon the arbitrary sequence of points in the input geometry???

Comment: It is a very good question. From what I have been able to glean from playing with my own cubes, is that the first two sides are opposing, ie, they vary in only one of the dimensions and the remaining 4 sides, share two points with adjacent sides, as you would expect. This is not the case for your example above, but, it may be a red herring.

Comment: DT_Dump returns PolygonZ not points, for what it is worth. So, again, using an example from a cube created from ST_Expand and ST_Extrude, the following works, well, it returns two TINs, which is not quite the same thing: `WITH
  cube1 (geom) AS (
     SELECT
         ST_Extrude(
             ST_Force3D(
                 ST_Expand(
                     ST_Makepoint(0.5, 0.5),
                  0.5, 0.5)),
         0,0,1)
       )
, dumped (geom) as (SELECT (ST_Dump(geom)).geom FROM cube1)
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Tesselate(ST_MakeSolid(ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(geom))))) from dumped;
`

Comment: Sorry, ignore previous, I was confusing ST_Dump with ST_DumpPoints.